# Función no modifica body

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo desarrollada una función en JS que ejecuta un AJAX, el AJAX trae bien la información sin problemas, con esos datos quiero incrustarlos en el código que ya tengo, no lo realiza, la intención de la siguiente función es traer 3 datos desde las DB dado un parámetro(ya lo hace), cuando sea exitoso, debería armar 1 div, con las clases `carousel-item active` crear una etiqueta `<img>` y añadirle como atributo uno de los valores que contiene el resultado del AJAX, a su vez añadir el `<img>` al div que creo antes, pero no crea ninguno de los 2 elementos, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
function GetEvidenceScrap(idscrapp) {

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "Coordinador/GetEvidenceScrap",
        contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'idscarp': idscrapp.value },
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                var carousel = document.getElementById('CI_' + idscrapp);
                if (i = 0) {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = 'carousel-item active';
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    div.append(img);
                    img.className('d - block w - 100');
                    img.src = '~/Evidence/' + result[i].rutevidencia;
                    carousel.append(div);
                }
                else
                {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = 'carousel-item';
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    div.append(img);
                    img.className('d - block w - 100');
                    img.src = '~/Evidence/' + result[i].rutevidencia;
                }
                
            }
           
        }
    });}
```

Notas:

La función la estoy llamando un con botón dentro del mismo    formulario, con el evento onclick
El resultado del json es como sigue, lo ejecute en el navegado de    forma independiente:

```js
[{"idRegistro":25,"idscrap":119,"rutevidencia":"21y06y202210m10m33am11.png"},{"idRegistro":26,"idscrap":119,"rutevidencia":"21y06y202210m10m33am22.jpg"},{"idRegistro":27,"idscrap":119,"rutevidencia":"21y06y202210m10m33am33.png"}]
```

Añado código HTML y C#

```html
<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen" id="A_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Evidence Scrap @item.IDScrap</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div id="@item.IDScrap" class="modal-body">
        @*
        <p>Aqui deberia ir las imagenes dependiendo el ID @item.IDScrap</p>*@
        <!--Carousel Evidence-->
        <div id="C_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div id="CI_@item.IDScrap" onload="GetEvidenceScrap(@item.IDScrap)" class="carousel-inner">
            <!--Creacion del carousel con evidencia-->

          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                                        </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" data-bs-slide="next">
                                                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                                        </button>
        </div>
        <!--End Carousel Evidence-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Código Backend:

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<Evidencia> GetEvidenceScrap(int idscrap)
    {
        var idscrapparametro = new SqlParameter("@idscrap", idscrap);
        var listaevidencescrap = _context.Evidencias.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM dbo.F_GetEvidenceScrap(@idscrap)", idscrapparametro);
        return listaevidencescrap.ToList();
    }
```

El resultado final debería poder armar un carousel de boostrap

Gracias

Comment: Donde esta tu referencia hacia el DOM, generas **DIVS**, agregas **Imágenes**, pero en donde?, debes de obtener mediante un Id, ClassName, tagName un elemento padre en tu html, posteriormente crear elementos hijos, al menos yo no veo esa referencia.

Comment: Gracias Antonio por responder, con la variable 'carousel' intento obtener el div padre donde quiero realizar la inserción

Comment: Si puedes agregar tu HTML y el Back que te da la respuesta. Has comprobado si realmente el Ajax cae en el **succes**, pueden ser varias cosas.

Comment: Añado el código,  y para validar si caía en el succes puse un alert, pero no cayo curiosamente

Comment: Ahi puede estar el problema, puedes agregar a tu Funcion Ajax antes del succes **beforeSend: function(){ //accion}**, despues del succes, **error: function(){//accion}**, con esto sabrás en que partes de la petición esta fallando.

Comment: Agregue los 2 elementos, pero me marca en la consola el mensaje de succes e inmediatamente el mensaje de error, a demás que mando Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () Actualización, ya valide porque arrojaba las 2 respuestas, era el método de envió de datos ya lo acomode, ahora solo arroja: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at